# Java Swing memory usage

Tags: java, swing, memory-management, jvm

There are plenty of questions on this issue, but no answer satisfied me; I'm coding a simple GUI window using Swing. Currently it only contains 4 buttons and one of them is opening a file chooser.

When I use VisualVM Monitoring tool to look at memory usage, the result is shown below:

[memory usage http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/3589/8txc.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/3589/8txc.png)

The first pike appeared when I clicked the button, then I did nothing else.

Is this normal for an idle application to consume 10M/min (when it is not doing anything?)

Since I have to do a quizz-like applet with an image, should I use to call `System.gc()` each time I switch to the next question to avoid (potentially huge?) memory usage?

Comment: Calling system.gc() programmatically frequently leads nowhere, since modern garbage collector implementations have its own heuristics to make cleansing or not.  I am not sure why your code does that, it may be just normal (please post the whole of it so I can have a try at that with jconsole up).  It would be interesting too to see its evolution past 6 minutes execution time.

Comment: *"There are plenty of questions on this issue, but no answer satisfied me"*  What, and not one of the answers to those questions pointed out that watching the memory of a Java app. is about as useful as gazing at your own navel for hours on end?  Worry about it when you see an `OutOfMemoryError`, then you have a memory leak that needs fixing.  Otherwise: if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Jorge_B: whiskeyspider's response shows you were right; I should have wait longer.

AndrewThompson: it's a weird way to care about memory, but I'll try to apply your advice in the future :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could recreate what you saw with a simple test program, but if you let the monitor track a little longer...

[image]

CPU was at 0% the whole time (just an open JFileChooser sitting there).  The memory fluctuations are curious, but I think the JVM must be doing all kinds of background management and maintenance tasks.  That work will use memory which eventually builds up.  And periodically it cleans up after itself.

Another thing to consider is that is this memory usage within the already allocated heap.  Your program is actually using a *consistent* amount of real memory the entire time, as you can see from the flat orange line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at the JFileChooser. When I used it, I noticed, that the fileChooser is "waiting" for something. And when I closed the program incorrectly, the fileChooser throws an Error. Maybe this will help you :)